# Game-App deep linking is working in all android phone, but it is not working in tablets . Do i need to add any manifest code to work it in Android?

Tags: unity, android, plugin

[image]

This is my manifest, which is used for App indexing auto complete and deep linking.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

we have to add the Screen support in Manifest file..